# What model of video card does a GeForce GT 620 qualify as?

Tags: windows-8, video, graphics-card, gaming

I recently got a new computer with a GeForce GT 620 video card and I'm trying to determine which games it will run.  Specifically "Aliens: Colonial Marines".  There's a page with a drop down menu that lets you select your card here:

http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=514&game=Aliens:%20Colonial%20Marines

but I have no idea which option to select.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

430 = 530 = 620.  NVidia rebrands cards constantly.  Links such as [this](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Farea.autodesk.com%2Fforum%2Ft73287&ei=heEVUeCtA-yDyAHrlYFo&usg=AFQjCNHUowL0LHH6j39dbxsleASyNguNDQ) state as such, but just throw 'rebrand 620 530' into Google to see the unofficial acknowledgements.

At the low-end range with NVidia, you can expect just about every card you touch to be rebranded to/from.

Additionally, there are [online tools](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/&ei=2uIVUZLQIeKsywGKnYDQAg&usg=AFQjCNEdydS3pxgs3cxMBpee3DAID65Sig) to automate specific game concerns (including your own game).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're confused by the fact that there's multiple models listed. [image]. The first model listed is the standard model, and the second one has half the ram. The 'GT620 Core GF108' seems to use a different core than the GF119 based model listed on wikipedia, and the rest are models specific to various card makers - these can be differenciated by the amount of ram they have or other factors. To make things worse, the OEM model uses a different core.

The simplest way to sort this out is to grab a copy of [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) - (apologies for the asus branded version - its what I have installed)- this should give you a definitive answer on what your video card is.

[image]

I've highlighted the necessary bits - its likely yours is one of the first 3, and the core type and ram amount (1gb is standard) should determine between them

Answer (score -1):

Nvidia, 600 series, GeForce GT 620.

Edited to add: What I'm describing above is the **exact** answer to the question posted.

> There's a page with a drop down menu that lets you select your card here:
>   http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=514&game=Aliens:%20Colonial%20Marines
>   but I have no idea which option to select. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You need to explain your answer, as this isn't going to make sense to the OP.

Comment: @DragonLord au contraire, I specifically answered the EXACT QUESTION they asked. They said there was a drop down list and they didn't know what to click. I looked at it, and wrote down what they need to click to find their video card. Once again, superuser community discourages me.